# Mac OS X: at command not working

Tags: mac, unix

I am going to schedule a job by using at command. Here I tried the following command:

```
$ at now + 1 minute
echo 'Test at command'
<EOD>
```

I saw the job is scheduled by using at -l. However, I saw no echo out.

I guess that I may need to add user to at.allow file. I cannot find at.allow in my Mac (Snow Leopard). Not sure what I need to do to test this at command?

Comment: I tried to read info from man at. It mentioned that "If the file _PERM_PATH/at.allow exists, only usernames mentioned in it are allowed to use at... If ... at.allow does not exists, _PERM_PATH/at.deny is checked,.." I am not sure what _PERM_PATH is.

Comment: In the case of Apple OSX Leopard, PERM_PATH for "at" is /usr/lib/cron.

Comment: For Mac OS X Lion it's `/var/at`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To enable the needed `atrun` daemon, as `man atrun` says, execute:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

as root (e.g. via `sudo`). Once you've done that, `/var/at/` will be the key directory (though the simplest way is to use `at` as root -- e.g., once again, by `sudo`!-).

Comment: I know that you need to be root to enable the atrun daemon, but you do not need to be root to run "at" commands.  (Unless those commands require root.)

Comment: does this activation or atrun survive reboots?

Comment: According to the man page yes, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: if `/var/at/at.deny` is empty you don't need to be root to queue at jobs, otherwise you can add your username to `/var/at/at.allow`.

Comment: I should read the man pages first... Thanks!

Comment: tested on yosemite, I had to wait 20 extra seconds before the job was actually executed (print to a file, do not echo because it won't show in the console)

Comment: It's now May, 2019. This answer was correct for some older versions of macos, but it's not a complete answer for Mojave. There's a [current, up-to-date answer on the U&L SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478840/286615).

Comment: It's now August, 2022 & this answer hasn't been edited. -1

Answer (score 15):

In Snow Leopard you need to:

1. Edit the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist`, change the disabled child node from `true` -> `false`.
2. Unload the current `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist` with:

   ```
   sudo launchctl unload -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
   ```

   Then load the edited version

   ```
   sudo launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
   ```
3. Test that it works with:

   ```
   echo blah | at now+1
   ```
4. In case the echo fails for a different reason, you should be able to at least see the queue get cleared with:

   ```
   atq
   ```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me on OSX 10.10 Yosemite.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this on OS X Lion and it seemed to work.

First enable the `atrun` deamon:

```
launchctl load -w
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

Then add [your username] to `/var/at/at.allow`.

When executed you will receive output at `/var/mail/[your username]`

I find that queued items with `batch` take a few minutes to get actually get executed.

Answer (score 3):

Others have replied about **at** being disabled on Mac OS X, and I don't know about that, but there is another problem: Where do you expect your **echo** command to print its message? On other Unix systems that I have used it does *not* print in the same shell window where you gave the **at** command. Remember that when the **at** job is run, you might not even be logged in any more.

Try to write something to a file instead, and see if that file appears at the right time.

Comment: The man page states, that the output will be mailed to you.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, and that worked well in the 1980's, when mail was handled locally on the same machine, but my experience (with other types of Unix than Mac OS X) is that nowadays you shouldn't expect to get any mail.

Answer (score 2):

The `launchctl` step wasn't enough for me; [Seamus's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working#comment2177236_43680) pointed me to a [more recent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478840/141153).

The TL;DR is you also need to add `/usr/libexec/atrun` at System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access.

Answer (score 0):

My installation of OS X (10.4) says in `man at`:

```
NOTE
     at, batch, atq, atrm are all disabled by default on Mac OS X.
```

Have you enabled `atrun` according to the instructions there?

Comment: I tried to find where is atrun in my Mac. From web, another option is to add user to at.allow. I could not find this file (at.allow) neither.