# Run Script on OSX Automatically

Tags: macos, scheduled-tasks, sh

How can I run a script I made on my mac automatically.

It needs to run once a day. Because it requires rsync the mac needs to be connected to the internet and I have realised when it is sleeping wifi isn't connected.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use automator to create a plugin and have iCal run it as an alarm action. Schedule the alarm to run daily

Answer (score 1):

See this answer for the "how to run daily" part of your question: [How can I get a script to run every day on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/126907/how-can-i-get-a-script-to-run-every-day-on-mac-os-x)

Because of how launchd works, it will run the command on wake if the scheduled time passed while your computer was asleep.