# run daemon on start when scheduled time is missed

Tags: macos, bash, launchd, daemon

I have a daemon/script that runs daily, but I can't find a way to make it run if the computer was off at the scheduled time.  Specifically, I'd like:

- run script/daemon once a day at a X:00 am
- if computer is off/sleeping at X:00, runs immediately when it wakes
- if daemon misses scheduled runs (off for several days), it runs once immediately when it wakes

The first point is handled easily with:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
```

Running on startup/login when the scheduled time is "missed" is not the (default) behavior of launch agents, despite the suggestion (and later correction) in this question:

[How can I get a script to run every day on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/126907/how-can-i-get-a-script-to-run-every-day-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Is this a LaunchDaemon (runs as root) or a LaunchAgent (runs as regular users when they're logged in)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I can run it as either